# How can I terminate a running Maven build in NetBeans?

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, process

If I run a Maven build in NetBeans which starts a long-running Java process (for example a HTTP listener or a JMX agent), terminating the process seems to have no effect. So I have to restart NetBeans and terminate the processes manually. I am using NetBeans 6.5 and 6.7 RC 1 on Windows XP and Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's broken in current versions of Netbeans, see: http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=135475

What I do is just stop the build and then go find the Java process and kill it. Just make sure you kill the Maven build process and not the IDE. No need to restart Netbeans. If your process has an alternate way to shut down (like Tomcat's shutdown command) you could just create a custom Maven goal using the exec plugin that ran that.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it looks like work on this issue is already in progress (see netbeans build integration note dated Sat Jun 20 07:07:41).

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed in NetBeans 6.8 :)